# Slowness when running svn info -r HEAD?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am writing a script to retrieve the head revision of a large number of files. I am currently using the command svn info -r HEAD  where the list of files are the absolute file path on disk.

For example:
svn info -r HEAD D:/abc/file1.txt D:/abc/file2.txt

Just executing this on a command prompt in Windows, the operation seems to take approximately 1 second per file. Is this meant to be so slow?

The svn server is part of our local network so network traffic shouldn't be an issue. Is this the best way to retrieve the head revision number or is there a quicker command?

Comment: No, it is not meant to be slow. What SVN versions do you run on the client and server? Is there an antivirus or proxy?

Comment: I am using TortoiseSVN 1.9.7 which according to the website is linked with Subversion 1.9.7. We are not using any additional antivirus beyond the Windows builtin Windows Defender.

Comment: Just to add, I did another test, it seems running svn info -r HEAD -R D:/abc is way faster than running svn -r HEAD on each file in the folder.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior where running svn info -r HEAD takes 1 second for each file that is passed as argument. Wondering if you have figured out a solution for that?